# Vue/Vuetify wrapper component of input doesn't inherit `hide-details` parameter

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've created a wrapper around the `v-select` input in `Vuetify`. Besides custom props, the `v-select` has `v-bind="$props"` attribute to inherit all the props.

I noticed that although it works for most props, it doesn't work for `hide-details`

```
<mywrapper label="Label" hide-details></mywrapper>
```

The label is automatically set for the `v-select` inside the `mywrapper` component, but `hide-details` isn't.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `hide-details` is `undefined` by default, because it can be boolean or string.

You need to use the following syntax:

```
<mywrapper label="Label" hide-details="true"></mywrapper>
```